# shiny apps not running/hanging/not working

Tags: r, shiny

I have installed shiny on R and when I try to run the "default" shiny app generated in RStudio (the Old Faithful Geyser app), nothing happens. Everything just appears to hang (no "listening" message, nothing). I can wait a long time, but nothing ever happens - not even the stop button in RStudio works.
I tried running the app from R directly but there is the same problem, so it does not appear related to RStudio.
I have also tried other apps that I have written but again it is the same problem.

Any ideas? Sorry, this is really vague, but it is hard to be more precise when there is no error, nothing at all.

Here is the sessionInfo().

Thank you!

Rory

```
sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] shiny_1.6.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_4.1.0    fastmap_1.1.0     ellipsis_0.3.2    magrittr_2.0.1    R6_2.5.0          promises_1.2.0.1  later_1.2.0      
 [8] htmltools_0.5.1.1 tools_4.1.0       Rcpp_1.0.6        digest_0.6.27     xtable_1.8-4      httpuv_1.6.1      lifecycle_1.0.0  
[15] mime_0.11         rlang_0.4.11
```

Comment: on Rstudio topleft you have the "RunApp" button, have you tried to unroll it and select "run external" ? by default it is set on "run in viewer pane"
I have no idea if it will change anything but sometimes my apps don't work outside of the browser

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @gdevaux Yes, I did try this, and unfortunately it makes no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by removing all packages and reinstalling R and R Studio (to the same versions, but anyway). This worked. I have no idea how, but at least it is a working solution.
Thanks to all who gave it some thought!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue occur (same R version of 4.1.0 and RStudio 1.4.1717). I didn't have to quite uninstall/reinstall my setup, but a simple `update.packages(ask = F)` did the trick for me.

Comment: Okay, thank you, Adam! If I run into the same problem again, I will try your solution.